# How can I repeat the loop if a result is not a number?

Tags: javascript, do-while

I'm trying something does loop for hashes variable by (do, while) loop but the page repeats the loop every time weather I write digits or characters so, How can I check if the prompt result out is a digit, not any characters.

here's my code:

```
function pick_number(arg)
{
    var hash = "#",
        set_new_hash = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arg; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < arg; j++)
        {
            document.body.innerHTML += hash;
            console.log(hash);
        }        
        for (var j = arg - 1; j > i ; j--)
        {
            document.body.innerHTML += " ";
            console.log(" ");
        }         
        document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";
    }
}

var x = '';

do 
{
    x = pick_number(prompt("Pick a number"));    
} while (typeof x != 'number');
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the argument to a number, then check if it's `NaN`:

```
function pick_number(arg) {
  const num = Number(arg);
  if (Number.isNaN(num)) {
    return;
  }
  // rest of the code; use `num` here
}
let x;
do {
  x = pick_number(prompt("Pick a number"));
} while (x === undefined);
```

Comment: I didn't try your code but what I need to understand, if I create a return like you do in -> **if (number.isNaN(num)) {return;}**, I think the loop will break down so, how the loop will repeat itself if I used return?

Comment: The `while (x === undefined)` test will result in the loop continuing if the input isn't a number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex test:

```js
do {
    x = pick_number(prompt("Pick a number"));    
} while (!/^\d+$/.test(x));
```